# understanding difference between int and setting variable equal to a number

Tags: swift, integer

What is the difference between setting a variable like

```
var eventNumber: Int = 1
```

and

```
var eventNumber = 1
```

Do I have to declare eventNumber as a Int?

I am using it essentially as a stepper. so depending on what took place before an action, I would call

```
eventNumber += 1
```

Comment: "What is the difference between setting a variable like" - no difference. Usually Swift can figure out the type automatically, so you don't need to explicitly say that `1` is an `Int`.

Comment: This is called [Type Inference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID322).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference. The compiler can figure out what the type is without you explicitly saying what it is.